# How to refactor ternarny operator

Tags: typescript

I have
`format = fromNow ? '' : 'LLL'`
I saw somewhere that it can be used like that
`format = fromNow && 'LLL',` which i thought means = 
`if fromNow is true then 'LLL' else nothing` but I get an error

> Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: It seems the && returns either the left hand side (bool) or the right hand side (string) but a string is required. You probably need an optional string on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which i thought means = if fromNow is true then 'LLL' else nothing

That's not what it means. `x && y` means:

1. Evaluate `x`
2. If the value from Step 1 is [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), take that value as the result of the `&&` operation and stop
3. If the value from Step 1 is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), evaluate `y` and take that value as the result of the `&&` operation

So if your `fromNow` is a boolean, `fromNow && 'LLL'` results in either `false` or `'LLL'` — that is, a boolean or a string. But apparently your `format` variable is declared as type `string`, so TypeScript won't let you assign a boolean to it.

Your original, using the conditional operator,¹ is preferable if you want a string result either way. You **could** do `fromNow && 'LLL' || ''` but that's getting a bit convoluted, whereas the conditional operator version is simple and clear.

---

¹ The proper name of the `? :` operator is the *conditional* operator. It's **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands, just like a binary operator accepts two and a unary operator accepts one), and for now it's JavaScript's only ternary operator, but that could change. :-)